# How to have chapter heading style different in chapters with number and chapter without numbers?

Tags: chapters, titlesec, thesis

I use the following code to change the chapter heading style

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16,45}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\flushright\normalsize\color{RoyalRed}
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\hspace{1ex} \thechapter}{1pc}
  {{\titlerule[0pt]}\vspace{1pc}\MakeUppercase}
```

However I would not like to center the heading for chapters with chapter numbers that is when I use `\chapter{Chapter1}` instead of `\chapter*{Abstract}`. I want two different heading style dependent on `\chapter` or `\chapter*`.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For setting snippets of code, type it, select it and click ont the `{}` button. For inline code, place it between back quotes as I did in my edit.

Comment: You can define the "numberless" chapter headings with `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}...`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by egreg, you can use

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {}{1pc}
  {{\titlerule[0pt]}\vspace{1pc}\MakeUppercase}
```

I have added some lines for `\titlespacing` also. Adjust the values as you like.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,showframe}    %% showframe just for demo
\usepackage{titlesec}

\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16,45}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\centering\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\flushright\normalsize\color{RoyalRed}
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\hspace{1ex} \thechapter}{1pc}
  {{\titlerule[0pt]}\vspace{1pc}\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {}{1pc}
  {{\titlerule[0pt]}\vspace{1pc}\MakeUppercase}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{*30}                     %% adjust 30 as per need default is 50
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{0pt}{*30}     %% adjust 30 as per need

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Some chapter with number}
  \chapter*{Un-numbered chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]